# Blurry screen but clear screenshot, RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, graphics

I installed the nVidia drivers for my Quadro 2000 card using the [ElRepo repositories](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kmod-nvidia). The install went fine and I ran `nvidia-xconfig` which generated a new `xorg.conf` file to use.

However, my monitor (a [BenQ BL2710PT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D7IG5N8)) displays the X-environment as blurry. Despite this the screenshot comes out as the correct resolution (2560 x 1440) looking clear.

I'm assuming this is something to do with the `xorg.conf` file, but I can't figure it out. I have added the lines

```
Option        "DPI" "109 x 109"
DisplaySize   596.8 335.6  #in millimeters
```

to the `xorg.conf` file under `Section "Monitor"`, but that did not resolve the issue.

I should note that I had the same issue **before** I installed the nVidia drivers. This is a fresh install of RHEL and I thought the blurriness may be an issue of not using the correct drivers.

The monitor is recognized and shows it being displayed at the correct resolution, so I'm at a bit of a loss on what to tackle next. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking at the screenshot on this monitor or a different device?

Comment: @drewbenn I get `xdpyinfo: unable to open display ""`; guessing I should start there.

Comment: @casey I emailed it to myself and opened it on the same monitory hooked up to a different machine, the screenshot is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being not having a duo-link DVI support from my graphics card. It scaled to 1920x1080 just fine, but doesn't support 2560x1440 @ 60Hz. There are apparently some workarounds to get to 2560x1440, but I'm happy with 1080p since it's not my main machine.